# Parsing number from text using regular expression in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have this code that I need to parse the process ID from text:

```java
@Test
public void testParseProcessId() {
    String text = "Private property of Exodus: 1016@localhost";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^Private property of Exodus:\\s(\\d+)");
    String matched = null;
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        matched = matcher.group(1);
    }
    assertEquals("1016", matched);
}
```

The test fails, but *I have checked the the regex should be correct*, what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need a regex here? The string seems to be quite static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `matches()` returns only true if the whole string can be matched.

You should change the regex: `^Private property of Exodus:\\s(\\d+).*$` to get a full match. This way `matcher.matches()` results `true`